# How do I show that dy/dx does not equal zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, implicit-differentiation

The equation of a curve is $2x^2-3xy+y^2=5$.

1. Find the equations of the tangent and normal to the curve at point $(4,3)$.
2. Show that there is no point on the curve at which the tangent is parallel to the x-axis.
3. Show that every line parallel to the x-axis cuts the curve at two distinct points.

For part 1, I was able to get the answer. however, for part 2, I was stuck. I thought of trying to show that $dy/dx$ cannot equals to zero. But how do I do that?

Comment: $2x^2 - 3xy + y^2$ is not an equation.

Comment: (1) We need $dy/dx$. Differentiate the equation $2x^2-3xy(x)+y(x)^2=5$ with respect to $x$. We get $4x-3y(x)-3x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y(x)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. From this we can solve for $dy/dx$ to get $dy/dx=(4x-3y(x))/(3x-3y(x))$. We put $x=4$ and $y(4)=3$ and get $dy/dx=(4^2-3^2)/(3\cdot 4-3^2)$. This is the slope of the tangent at $(4,3)$. The slope of the normal will bet the opposite of the reciprocal of this number. With the slope of a line and the point $(4,3)$ through which it must pass you get the equation of the line.

Comment: (2) We computed above the slope of the tangent. $dy/dx=(4x-3y)/(3x-3y)$. For this slope to be parallel to the $x$-axis we will need it to be $\infty$. We get this when the denominator is zero $x=y$. But if we put $x=y$ in the original equation we get $0=2x^2-3x^2+x^2=5$, which is impossible.

Comment: (3) A line parallel to the $x$-axis has equation $y=a$ for some constant $a$. We put this into the equation and get $2x^2-3ax+a^2-5=0$. This has two solutions if and only if the discriminant of this polynomial with unknown $x$ is positive. The discriminant is $9a^2-8(a^2-5)=a^2+40$, which is always positive ($\geq 40$).